# Collapse specific multiindex columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm importing an Excel file which has the following structure:

```
|    | Cat 1 |    |    |    | Cat 2 |    |    | Total |
|code|   a   |  b |  c |  d |   a   |  b |  c |       |
|data| data  |data|data|data| data  |data|data| data  |
```

I want to keep the information in the double header row so I use:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet, header=[0,1]
```

But this gives me the following MultiIndex: `print(df.columns)`:

```
MultiIndex([('Unnamed: 0_level_0',              'code'),
            (             'Cat 1',                 'a'),
            (             'Cat 1',                 'b'),
            etc.
            (             'Cat 2',                 'a'),
            (             'Cat 2',                 'b'),
            etc.
            (             'Total','Unnamed: 8_level_1')],)
```

I'm looking for a way to collapse the `unnamed: x_level_y` columns so I can access them simply with `df['code']` or `df['Total']`. I've tried `df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0_level_0: ''})`, but this isn't generalisable if I don't know which levels are missing, and doesn't allow me to access the column with just the single layered name. The other answers I've found are about removing any columns which contain `Unnamed` in the column name, but I want to keep the columns and the data they contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-create the MultiIndex and put the existing name in level 0 for all columns where any level contains `Unnamed`:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(c[1],'') if 'Unnamed' in c[0] else 
     (c[0],'') if 'Unnamed' in c[1] else
     c 
     for c in df.columns.to_list()])
```

Comment: Just for reference, you can then access columns with just the single name: `df['code']` rather than `df['']['code']`

Comment: @thosphor: yes of course :)  this was one of your requirements you wrote in the question

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to demean your answer. It just wasn't obvious to me from reading it that it would be possible, but I wanted to assure that I'd tested it and it worked.